# c3js graph from PHP/MySQL data for multi-series histogramm

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, graph

I'm trying to create a graph of pageviews for our intranet split by business unit. 
I log every page view in a table in MySQL and so far have managed to create this query:

```
SELECT unit_name, COUNT(l_ID) AS counter, DATE_FORMAT(l_time, "%d/%m/%Y") AS day FROM log, units WHERE l_time >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY) AND unit_ID = l_uID AND l_action = 'pageview' GROUP BY day, l_uID ORDER BY day ASC
```

I get a row per unit and per day (and if there has been no visit on a day there is no row). 
I'm trying to put that into a nice graph to see day by day who has been most active (kinda like a Google Analytics graph but with a line per unit) but am struggling to translate it into the format that c3js needs. Any input?

here the table layout I get (could change it of course, open to input):

```
date       // unit   // number of visits
11/11/2019 // Unit A // 7
11/11/2019 // Unit B // 4
12/11/2019 // Unit A // 2
13/11/2019 // Unit A // 5
13/11/2019 // Unit B // 6
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I ended up figuring it out by tweaking my php code, here it is:

```
$sql = 'SELECT unit_name, unit_ID, COUNT(l_ID) AS counter, DATE_FORMAT(l_time, "%d/%m/%Y") AS day FROM log, units WHERE l_time >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY) AND unit_ID = l_uID AND l_action = "pageview" GROUP BY day, l_uID ORDER BY unit_name, day ASC';
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
if(!$statement->execute()) { die("Query error: ".$statement->error); } 
$histo = $statement->get_result();
$totalRows_histo = $histo->num_rows;

$sql = 'SELECT unit_ID, unit_name, COUNT(l_ID) AS counter, DATE_FORMAT(l_time, "%d/%m/%Y") AS day FROM log, units WHERE l_time >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY) AND unit_ID = l_uID AND l_action = "pageview" GROUP BY unit_ID';
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
if(!$statement->execute()) { die("Query error: ".$statement->error); } 
$histo_short = $statement->get_result();
$totalRows_histo_short = $histo_short->num_rows;

$i = 0;
$day = ""; $counter = "";
$unit[$i] = "";

while($row_histo = $histo->fetch_object()) {
    $i++;
    $unit[$i] = $row_histo->unit_ID;

    $day .= '"'.$row_histo->day.'", ';
    $counter .= ''.$row_histo->counter.', ';

    if($unit[$i] != $unit[$i-1]) {
        $label_day[$row_histo->unit_ID] = '["unit'.$row_histo->unit_ID.'day" , '.rtrim($day, ", ").']'." \n";
        $label_counter[$row_histo->unit_ID] = '["unit'.$row_histo->unit_ID.'counter" , '.rtrim($counter, ", ").']'." \n";       
        $day = ""; $counter = "";
    }
}
$overall_day = "";
$overall_counter = "";
$col = "";
$names = "";
while($row_histo_short = $histo_short->fetch_object()) {
    $overall_day .= $label_day[$row_histo_short->unit_ID].", ";
    $overall_counter .= $label_counter[$row_histo_short->unit_ID].", ";

    $col .= "unit".$row_histo_short->unit_ID."counter: 'unit".$row_histo_short->unit_ID."day', \n";

    $names .= "unit".$row_histo_short->unit_ID."counter: '".$row_histo_short->unit_name."', \n";
}
$histo->data_seek(0);
```

basically what I do is that I loop through all rows of the table, ordered by unit and when the unit changes compared to the previous row I save that in a new array number (not sure if that makes sense). 
The second MySQL/PHP request is to get the legend and the columns right for c3js per following code:

```
<script>
c3.generate({
        bindto: '#pageviews',
            data: {
                xs: {
                    <?php echo rtrim($col, ", \n"); ?>
                },
                columns: [
                    <?php echo $overall_day.rtrim($overall_counter, ", \n"); ?>
                ],
                type: 'timeseries',
                xFormat: '%d/%m/%Y',
                names: {
                  <?php echo rtrim($names, ", \n"); ?>
                }
            },
            axis: {
                x: {
                    type: 'timeseries',
                    tick: {
                        format: '%d/%m/%Y'
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                  show: true,
            },

            padding: {
                bottom: 15,
                top: 0
            },
    });
</script>
```

Hope that helps someone in need at one point!
It's not perfect as my loop seems to be attributing the data to the wrong units but we're getting there, will update in due course